# Solve equation for $|z| - z = 1+2i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve equation:

$|z| - z = 1+2i$

I know that we can express $|z|$ as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $z$ as $x+yi$ but I get stuck after some steps.

$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-(x+yi) = 1+2i$

If going by that can we say that?:
$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x = 1$ and $-yi=2i$

I'm getting stuck after this part (which I hope was not wrong).

Comment: Yes, so $y = -2$, and you want to find all $x$ such that $\sqrt{x^2+4} = x+1$.

Answer (score 2):

The equation can be rewritten as: $$\;z = |z| -1-2i\;\tag{1}$$

Then:

$$
\begin{align}
|z|^2 = z \bar z & = (|z| - 1 - 2i)\,(|z| - 1 + 2i) \\
 &= |z|^2 +|z|(-1+2i-1-2i) +(-1-2i)(-1+2i)\\
 &= |z|^2  - 2 |z| + 5
\end{align}
$$

Canceling the $|z|^2$ term between the first and last expressions gives $|z|= \frac{5}{2}$ then substituting in $(1)$:

$$z = \frac{5}{2} - 1 - 2i = \frac{3}{2} - 2i$$

Answer (score 0):

Since two complex numbers are equal iff their real and imaginary part are equal, compare them in both sides:

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x-iy=1+2i\iff \begin{cases}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x=1\\{}\\y=-2\end{cases}$$

and etc.